# Pure CSS/JQuery Solution to center/crop different sized images in a set sized div box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, crop

I am working on a community website with thumbnails of slightly different sizes.

I have a div box set at 165x165 pixels.

Some full sized thumbnails images end up being 165 pixels, others 180, 192, 205, etc.

What I'd like to do is always force these to display horizontally centered inside the div box at no wider than 165 pixels. Therefore should an image be 185 pixels horizontally it will crop off 10 pixels to the left and 10 pixels to the right. An image of 205 pixels horizontally would be cropped 20 pixels on each side.

Unfortunately I won't have access to server side code for this so it has to all be accomplished javascript and/or jquery.

The biggest challenge I see with this is that the image sizes are always changing.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to put `overflow:hidden` on the `<div>` and let the browser deal with the clipping. Something like this:

```
<div style="width: 165px; height: 165px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img ...>
</div>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/M3FzZ/

If you need to do this in jQuery, then:

```
$('div-selector').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Where "div-selector" is whatever selector you need to get your `<div>`s.

Comment: This works perfect for what was asked, i dont know why he never accepted your answer, great answer! The jQuery really helped me.